# Chrome Extension: How do I inject CSS and Javascript into a certain URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension that changes the website of ROBLOX back to the 2016 UI and other stuff.

I currently have this UI in the popup:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfxUK.png)

I already have some code to make the checkboxes work, but how do I actually make them add some CSS and Javascript to https://roblox.com?

**Edit**: I already checked [How to inject CSS into webpage through Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619095/how-to-inject-css-into-webpage-through-chrome-extension) but I want to do it programmatically.

Updates:

**Sunday, November 22, 2020 17:53** Googled more, still didn't find anything
**Monday, November 23, 2020 17:40** Googled more, still didn't find anything. Please answer! Nothing helps or works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should get you started:
you need to inject it into the tab you have the site open on, look at the example here on injecting CSS:
[Chrome extension: insertCSS once per tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020244/chrome-extension-insertcss-once-per-tab)

It won't be as simple as that and you'll need to add logic to replace the css via the content script.

To inject a content script:

```
import browser from "webextension-polyfill";
    
await browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
     file: "/static/js/content.js",
});
```

Add `/static/js/content.js` and any files you want to inject to your manifest

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make it work for only certain domains? E.g. roblox.com

Comment: You request permission only to that site https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Also you can check which page you're on before injecting.

Comment: @K14F4r sorry for the very late reply, I got caught up with lots of stuff. But thanks.